# ASP .NET Core DI: Dependency on single implementation of multiple registrations of service type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

**Problem**

I have a DI scenario where I have multiple classes that implement a common interface (`IModelService`).

I'm using a generic framework class (`PredictionEnginePool<,>`) that has options injected (`PredictionEnginePoolOptions<>`). This has a property (`ModelLoader`) that must be set using `AddOptions` in `Startup.ConfigureServices` where I set it to an instance of `CustomModelLoader` obtained from the service provider (from the `AddSingleton` implementation factory) during options configuration. `CustomModelLoader` depends on a single `IModelService` for its lifetime, so it needn't be injected with `IEnumerable<IModelService>`.

**Research**

I have researched various patterns to achieve my aim which is to have `CustomModelLoader` have access to a single registered `IModelService` object while being assigned to the `ModelLoader` property of the options class `PredictionEnginePoolOptions<,>` (which is then injected into `PredictionEnginePool<,>`). But most of the solutions I've found use a service locator anti-pattern or break SRP and/or OCP; for example, most of the solutions offered on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39174989/197591). And many people suggest that the built-in DI framework of .NET Core is too simple to cater for complex scenarios and to use something like Autofac or StructureMap.

However, I refuse to believe that Microsoft would make such a scenario difficult or impossible (as it's not *that* complicated) in a new modern framework as .NET Core which builds on almost two decades of experience from .NET Framework. I've been pretty impressed with .NET Core so far in terms of complying with and enabling SOLID and other good coding principles.

**Own Attempt So Far**

The code below shows my attempt to resolve this based on various related questions on SO. Basically, to provide `CustomModelLoader` with a single `IModelService` object, I inject options into it (`CustomModelLoaderOptions`). This has a `IModelService` property on it. To set this, I have another call to `AddOptions` which sets the property (`ModelService`) by getting the single `IModelService` object that returns `true` from `CanTrain` (a strategy design pattern). I use `GetServices<IModelService>` to resolve the `IModelService` objects. `CanTrain` is implemented in each concrete type (`RegressionModelService` and `TimeSeriesModelService`) to state whether it can work with the type specified at startup for each generic version of `PredictionEnginePool` (`RegressionPrediction` and `TimeSeriesPrediction` which are just simple POCOs).

These are the interfaces and classes:

```
interface IModelService
{
    bool CanTrain(Type type);
}

class RegressionModelService : IModelService
{
    public bool CanTrain(Type type) => type == typeof(RegressionPrediction);
}

class TimeSeriesModelService : IModelService
{
    public bool CanTrain(Type type) => type == typeof(TimeSeriesPrediction);
}

class CustomModelLoaderOptions
{
    public IModelService ModelService { get; set; }
}

class CustomModelLoader : ModelLoader
{
    public CustomModelLoader(IOptionsFactory<CustomModelLoaderOptions> options) {}
}
```

My only real restriction is `PredictionEnginePool<,>` and `PredictionEnginePoolOptions<,>`. These are framework classes that cannot change and must be registered as per below. The following code is in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddScoped<IModelService, RegressionModelService>();
services.AddScoped<IModelService, TimeSeriesModelService>();
services.AddScoped<CustomModelLoader>();

AddPredictionEnginePool<RegressionPrediction>();
AddPredictionEnginePool<TimeSeriesPrediction>();

void AddPredictionEnginePool<T>()
{
    services.AddSingleton<PredictionEnginePool<Input, T>>(sp =>
    {
        services.AddOptions<PredictionEnginePoolOptions<Input, T>>().Configure(options1 =>
        {
            services.AddOptions<CustomModelLoaderOptions>().Configure(options2 =>
            {
                options2.ModelService = sp.GetServices<IModelService>().Single(s => s.CanTrain(typeof(T)));
            });

            options1.ModeLoader = sp.GetService<CustomModelLoader>();
        });
    });
}
```

**Question**

I have spent many hours on this and I believe the above solution solves it without breaking SOLID principles (particularly SRP and OCP) and without using any anti-patterns. It's also using the built-in DI framework and avoids named instances.

However, I am not entirely happy with my solution because it still requires me to call `GetService` on the service provider to get `IModelService` and then assign it to a property on `CustomModelLoaderOptions` which is then injected into `CustomModelLoader`. I don't mind doing this for `CustomModelLoader` itself and assigning it to a property on `PredictionEnginePoolOptions<,>` which is then injected into `PredictionEnginePool<,>` as this is the [documented way](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/blob/master/samples/csharp/end-to-end-apps/DeepLearning_ImageClassification_TensorFlow/TensorFlowImageClassification/Startup.cs) (per the sample applications) to do it for this class, but I feel I'm just copying this methodology to work around another design problem that could be solved *without* having to call `GetService`, and somehow let the DI framework take care of it. Is this possible, perhaps with a different code design pattern?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the Factory Pattern. You almost have it with your implementation there but not quite.

What you need is to wrap up your logic into a single factory class, and return the instance based on some condition. The only thing that is injected then is the factory. This adds the benefit that code changes only have happen in one place.